# Category of vector spaces is monoidal closed

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

How to show that the category $\textbf{Vect}_k$ of vector spaces with ground field $k$ is monoidal closed? I am aware that the right adjoint to the functor $-\otimes Y$ should be $[Y,-]: X\mapsto \textbf{Vect}_k(Y,X)$, with unit $d_X : X\to [Y,X\otimes Y]$ and counit $e_X: [Y,X]\otimes Y\to X$. What are these linear maps explicitly?

Comment: The counit should be $e_X : [Y,X]\otimes Y\to X$. Are you asking about $d_X$ and $e_X$? Perhaps a better way to think of $[Y,X]$ is the vector space $Y^*\otimes X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need the unit and counit to define an adjunction: it's enough to show that the isomorphism
$$[X,\, [Y,Z]]\ \cong\ [X\otimes Y,\,Z]$$
given by observing that both sides basically give the *bilinear maps* $X\times Y\to Z$, is natural in $X$ and $Z$.

Nevertheless, $d_X(x)=y\mapsto x\otimes y$, and
$e_X:[Y,X]\otimes Y\to X$ is $\ e_x(f\otimes y)=f(y)$.